# Firebase Crashlytics setup won't complete

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I've recently updated to the latest version of Firebase via carthage along with this I've update things like crashlytics etc. I've followed the docs [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md) from Google and even enabled logging in the console to see everything that is happening.

I've forced a crash when I tap a button by calling the `fatalError()` function, and then re-opening the application so that any crash reports are sent to crashlytics. And upon examining it seems like this is the case. You can see the logs below.

```
2020-11-10 12:28:53.121736+0000 XXXX[10445:2257292] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 7.0.0
2020-11-10 12:28:53.150403+0000 XXXX[10445:2257492] 7.0.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics] Running on iPhone10,6, 14.1.0 (18A8395)
2020-11-10 12:28:53.179643+0000 XXXX[10445:2257492] 7.0.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Automatic data collection is enabled.
2020-11-10 12:28:53.179714+0000 XXXX[10445:2257492] 7.0.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Unsent reports will be uploaded at startup
2020-11-10 12:28:53.355265+0000 XXXX[10445:2257496] 7.0.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Preparing the report for the new endpoint: 1
2020-11-10 12:28:53.355919+0000 XXXX[10445:2257503] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Packaged report with id '2d5536e4afd146b0ac224658d99aa50e' for submission
2020-11-10 12:28:53.356323+0000 XXXX[10445:2257496] 7.0.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
2020-11-10 12:28:53.519303+0000 XXXX[10445:2257504] 7.0.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
2020-11-10 12:28:53.519402+0000 XXXX[10445:2257504] 7.0.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
2020-11-10 12:28:53.519480+0000 XXXX[10445:2257504] 7.0.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
2020-11-10 12:28:53.519979+0000 XXXX[10445:2257504] 7.0.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
2020-11-10 12:28:53.532612+0000 XXXX[10445:2257492] 7.0.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Regenerating Install ID
    "X-firebase-client" = "apple-platform/ios apple-sdk/18A8394 appstore/false deploy/zip device/iPhone10,6 fire-install/7.0.0 fire-ios/7.0.0 fire-rc/7.0.0 firebase-crashlytics/7.0.0 os-version/14.1 swift/true xcode/12A7403";
```

But for some reason and for the life of me I can't figure out why the dashboard doesn't seem to be updating in the dashboard. I just keep seeing the following message. Even though the logs above say the reports have been sent successfully. Also I've checked my plist to make sure it's pointing to the right project and it is since my analytic events are coming through too.

[image]